# Selective extracting and opening for zipfile in python

Tags: python, if-statement, file-io, zip, python-zipfile

From the docs, it looks like it's possible to perform selective file extract and open using the zipfile module in native python, http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile using

**`ZipFile.extract(member[, path[, pwd]])`**

> Extract a member from the archive to the current working directory;
>   member must be its full name or a ZipInfo object). Its file
>   information is extracted as accurately as possible. path specifies a
>   different directory to extract to. member can be a filename or a
>   ZipInfo object. pwd is the password used for encrypted files.

I have a zipfile as such `foobar.zip`:

```
foobar.zip\
  \foo
      \a.txt
      \b.txt
  \bar
      \b.txt
      \c.txt
```

I've tried to extract files from a single sub-directory of the .zip file but it prints nothing sometimes:

```
import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile('foobar.zip','r') as inzipfile:
  for infile in inzipfile.namelist():
    if 'foo' in os.path.split(infile)[0]:
      print inzipfile.open(infile,'r').read()
```

I've tried to give a list of selected files that i might want to extract but it also prints nothing sometimes too.

```
wanted = ['a.txt', 'b.txt']
import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile('foobar.zip','r') as inzipfile:
  for infile in inzipfile.namelist():
    if os.path.split(infile)[1] in wanted:
      print inzipfile.open(infile,'r').read()
```

**Edited:**
*There's nothing wrong with the code or how I'm reading the files*. I think there's something wrong with my zipfile which causes [schroedinbug](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/S/schroedinbug.html) where sometimes my sub-directory files don't open and `inzipfile.open(infile,'r').read()` returns None. Now it extracts, opens and print the content of the file.

**Any idea how to check within the python code, that all files in a .zip file can be opened with the selective extract/open method above?**

**How else can I perform selective extract/open of zipfiles?** Is there a more pythonic method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There *is* something wrong with your code. It's opening and reading the folder names which are also in `inzipfile.namelist()`. You can see this by simply:

```
print inzipfile.namelist()
```

Which will output:

```
['foobar/bar/', 'foobar/bar/b.txt', 'foobar/bar/c.txt', 'foobar/foo/', 
 'foobar/foo/a.txt', 'foobar/foo/b.txt', 'foobar/']
```

Another way to see it is with`inzipfile.printdir()`which should result in something along the following lines being printed:

```
File Name                                             Modified             Size
foobar/bar/                                    2014-01-12 08:53:36            0
foobar/bar/b.txt                               2014-01-12 08:54:08           60
foobar/bar/c.txt                               2014-01-12 08:54:28           60
foobar/foo/                                    2014-01-12 08:53:02            0
foobar/foo/a.txt                               2014-01-12 08:55:04           60
foobar/foo/b.txt                               2014-01-12 08:55:24           60
foobar/                                        2014-01-12 08:52:32            0
```

Notice that in both cases the name of all folder entries end with a`/`character. You can use that as a simple way to detect them:

```
import os
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile('foobar.zip', 'r') as inzipfile:
    for infile in (name for name in inzipfile.namelist() if name[-1] != '/'):
        if 'foo' in os.path.split(infile)[0]:
            print inzipfile.open(infile,'r').read(),
```

Likewise:

```
wanted = {'a.txt', 'b.txt'}  # use a set, it's faster for testing membership
import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile('foobar.zip','r') as inzipfile:
    for infile in (name for name in inzipfile.namelist() if name[-1] != '/'):
        if os.path.split(infile)[1] in wanted:
          print inzipfile.open(infile,'r').read()
```

The only way I can think of to check if all the [file] members of an archive can be opened, is to actually try doing it to each one:

```
def check_files(zipfilename):
    """ Check and see if all members of a .zip archive can be opened.
        Beware of vacuous truth - all members of an empty archive can be opened
    """
    def can_open(archive, membername):
        try:
            archive.open(membername, 'r')  # return value ignored
        except (RuntimeError, zipfile.BadZipfile, zipfile.LargeZipFile):
            return False
        return True

    with zipfile.ZipFile(zipfilename, 'r') as archive:
        return all(can_open(archive, membername)
                    for membername in (
                        name for name in archive.namelist() if name[-1] != '/'))
```