# Create Dataframe from a csv inside a zip file

Tags: python, pandas, unzip, zip

I am trying to read WGIData.csv file in a pandas dataframe. WGIData.csv is present inside a zip file which i am downloading from this url

http://databank.worldbank.org/data/download/WGI_csv.zip

But when i tried to read, it throws error **BadZipFile: File is not a zip file**

Here is my python code

```
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import urlopen
from zipfile import ZipFile

class Get_Data():

    def Return_csv_from_zip(self, url):
        self.zip = urlopen(url)
        self.myzip = ZipFile(self.zip)
        self.myzip = self.zip.extractall(self.myzip)
        self.file = pd.read_csv(self.myzip)
        self.zip.close()

        return self.file

url = 'http://databank.worldbank.org/data/download/WGI_csv.zip'
data = Get_Data()
df = data.Return_csv_from_zip(url)
```

Comment: Your zip has two files: `['WGIData.csv', 'WGISeries.csv']` this might be the problem.

Comment: It's not bad zip file, i extracted it using winrar @AChampion

Comment: Then what should i need to do?@coldspeed

Comment: i only want to read WGIData.csv

Comment: Something like this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21075999/4909087

Comment: `urlopen()` doesn't return a file that you can open with `ZipFile`, also `ZipFile` doesn't work with a stream, so you will need to have a `seek`able file like object for `ZipFile` to work.

Comment: Any suggestion to open this url and read file as a dataframe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`urlopen()` does not return an object (`HTTPResponse`) you can send to `ZipFile()`. You can `read()` the response and use `io.BytesIO()` to do what you need:

```
In []:
from io import BytesIO

z = urlopen('http://databank.worldbank.org/data/download/WGI_csv.zip')
myzip = ZipFile(BytesIO(z.read())).extract('WGIData.csv')
pd.read_csv(myzip)

Out[]:
     Country Name Country Code                                     Indicator Name    Indicator Code       1996  \
0        Anguilla          AIA                    Control of Corruption: Estimate            CC.EST        NaN   
1        Anguilla          AIA           Control of Corruption: Number of Sources         CC.NO.SRC        NaN   
2        Anguilla          AIA             Control of Corruption: Percentile Rank        CC.PER.RNK        NaN   
3        Anguilla          AIA  Control of Corruption: Percentile Rank, Lower ...  CC.PER.RNK.LOWER        NaN   
4        Anguilla          AIA  Control of Corruption: Percentile Rank, Upper ...  CC.PER.RNK.UPPER        NaN   
5        Anguilla          AIA              Control of Corruption: Standard Error        CC.STD.ERR        NaN   
...
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without specifying the file name?

Comment: You can `extractall()` to extract all the contents of a zip file or you can get the `namelist()` and iterate through the names.